# Convert string of list of dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dictionary, dataframe

This is df1:

```
     indexID    detail                                             object
0          0  [{'y2': 627, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1'...  Pedestrian
1          3  [{'y2': 699, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1'...  Pedestrian
2          6  [{'y2': 852, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1'...  Pedestrian
3          9  [{'y2': 595, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1'...  Pedestrian
4         12  [{'y2': 629, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1'...  Pedestrian
5         14  [{'y2': 586, 'frame': 7385, 'visibility': 0, '...  Pedestrian
```

Close look at the first cell in 'detail':

```
[{'y2': 627, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 603, 'score': 1, 'x2': 770, 'x1': 759, 'class': 1}, {'y2': 623, 'frame': 2, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 599, 'score': 1, 'x2': 777, 'x1': 766, 'class': 1}]
```

I am trying to convert df1 to a new dataframe where each row of the new dataframe corresponds to one dictionary of the list of dictionaries in df1, while retaining the indexID.

Assuming that the function to convert the data frame has been applied to the first row of df1, the converted dataframe will look like this:

```
frame   indexID x1  y1  x2  y2  score   class   visibility
  1         0   759 603 770 627   1       1          0
  2         0   766 599 777 623   1       1          0
```

**THINGS TO NOTE**:

- When I print the dataframe to my terminal it shows that the detail column is a list of dictionaries, as showed above. However, when I run `type(df1['detail'][0])`, it returns `<type 'str'>`.
- There are a lot more than 2 dictionaries in the detail column for each row.

Something I tried to convert the string to list of dictionaries:

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
            print ast.literal_eval(row['detail'])
```

However, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 283, in <module>
    print ast.literal_eval(row['detail'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

[Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jhb6nS_JP2_t4y5mRr99Y9gdYRtMVzFP) for CSV

Comment: Do you want to convert `[{'y2': 627, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 603, 'score': 1, 'x2': 770, 'x1': 759, 'class': 1}, {'y2': 623, 'frame': 2, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 599, 'score': 1, 'x2': 777, 'x1': 766, 'class': 1}]` this in to new df? If so `pd.DataFrame(l)` will convert ?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Yup! But that new dataframe also needs to have the corresponding indexID!

Comment: @RuvenGuna - Is created DataFrame from json? If yes, is possible share json?

Comment: @jezrael it is not. It is from a csv file. I will include it on the question.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - How working `df['detail'] = df['detail'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)` ?

Comment: @jezrael doing that gives me this error: `ValueError: Expected object or value`

Comment: @RuvenGuna - There is always value `Pedestrian` in all data?

Comment: @jezrael Yup. Actually, the object column is not really important. I only use the information in the indexID and detail column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some preprocessing before using `ast.literal_eval` - replace `][` to `],[` and converting to `tuple`s, then use list comprehension with flattening:

```
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)

df['detail'] = df['detail'].str.replace('][','],[', regex=False).apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['detail'] = [x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, ) for x in df['detail']]
#print (df)

s = df.set_index('indexID')['detail']
comp = {'{}_{}'.format(k, i): pd.DataFrame(x) for k, v in s.items() for i, x in enumerate(v)}
df = pd.concat(comp)
print (df.head())

       class  frame  score  visibility   x1   x2   y1   y2
0_0 0      1      1      1         0.0  759  770  603  627
    1      1      2      1         0.0  766  777  599  623
    2      1      3      1         0.0  770  786  593  618
    3      1      4      1         0.0  781  792  583  607
    4      1      5      1         0.0  786  800  573  597
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
t=[{'y2': 627, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 603, 'score': 1, 'x2': 770, 'x1': 759, 'class': 1}, {'y2': 623, 'frame': 2, 'visibility': 0, 'y1': 599, 'score': 1, 'x2': 777, 'x1': 766, 'class': 1}]
ind=df['indexID'].values

new_df= pd.DataFrame(t,index=ind)
print new_df
```

Output:

```
   class  frame  score  visibility   x1   x2   y1   y2
0      1      1      1           0  759  770  603  627
3      1      2      1           0  766  777  599  623
```

Explanation:

First create a dataframe from your list, then assign index externally.

EDIT-1:

```
df['detail']=df['detail'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
print pd.DataFrame(sum(df['detail'].values,[]),index=df['indexID'].values)
```

Input:

```
   indexID                                         detail      object
0        0     [{'y2': 627, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0}]  Pedestrian
1        3     [{'y2': 699, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0}]  Pedestrian
2        6     [{'y2': 852, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0}]  Pedestrian
3        9     [{'y2': 595, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0}]  Pedestrian
4       12     [{'y2': 629, 'frame': 1, 'visibility': 0}]  Pedestrian
5       14  [{'y2': 586, 'frame': 7385, 'visibility': 0}]  Pedestrian
```

Output:

```
    frame  visibility   y2
0       1           0  627
3       1           0  699
6       1           0  852
9       1           0  595
12      1           0  629
14   7385           0  586
```

Comment: This doesn't work because even though when I print the dataframe to my terminal it shows that the detail column is a list of dictionaries, when I run `type(df1['detail'][0])`, it returns <type 'str'>.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - you can convert that using `ast`

Comment: I tried that but I got an error. I have updated my question.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - It wokrs for your sample input. please note on Edit-1

Comment: @RuvenGuna - I think your data is not in expected format.

Comment: Oh. How do I change that?

Comment: without seeing the data it's hard to give suggestion. check which string caused harm